# xpath for-each multiple conditions

Tags: xslt, xpath

What is wrong with the following line?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Node1/Node2/Node3 [.!='Primary' or .!='Secondary' ]">
```

Trying to select all elements where Node3 is not Primary o Secondary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to find Node3 where the content is not Primary and not Secondary.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Node1/Node2/Node3[.!='Primary' and .!='Secondary' ]">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
not(. = 'Primary' or . = 'Secondary')
```

:)